# Keyboard layout: iBus or System Settings?

Tags: kubuntu, keyboard-layout, ibus

My Kubuntu 21.10 installation worked fine with three input layouts defined: DE, NO, EN (US). I could change layouts by pressing both CTRL-keys simultaneously, and the current layout was displayed in the system tray.

Then I discovered this little iBus thingy in the system tray and wondered what it does. It showed only one layout, DE. The pre-defined keyboard shortcut SUPER+Space didn't do anything. Then I added my other two layouts in the iBus configuration, and from this moment on everything was changed:

The CTRL-left + CTRL-right shortcut didn't work anymore. The little system tray announcer from the System Settings application was gone, only the iBus display remained showing DE, NO or EN. The layout could only be switched using the iBus applet.

When I changed keyboard settings in the System Settings application, the icon appeared again, but at least once things crashed and I couldn't type anymore and had to logout/login to have a keyboard again.

I think that this situation is not satisfying: Why do I have two incompatible methods to control my keyboard? Could I get rid off iBus anyhow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IBus is not installed by default in Kubuntu 21.10, so I would guess that you upgraded from Kubuntu 21.04 where IBus was installed by default.

In any case you don't seem to need IBus. The simplest way to disable it is to run this terminal command:

```
im-config -n none
```

and relogin.

Comment: Thx a lot for the answer, problem solved! - Just to let you know, the installation is only a few days old, so no upgrade took place.

Comment: @RatherVi: Then I have to ask: Have you installed zoom?

Comment: No, never used it in my whole life ;)

Comment: @RatherVi: Ok. Then I have no idea why IBus was installed.

Comment: Had this mysterious problem for half a year. After upgrade. Yes, had zoom before. Some day keyboard layouts were working by regular changer, some days not. Ibus layouts were different. Was too lazy to google whats wrong for a half year, because different layout was rarely needed.